# Pycharm debugger instantly exits with 139 code

Tags: pycharm, upgrade, segmentation-fault

After upgrade from `Pycharm 2017.2.3` to `Pycharm 2017.1.4` Pycharm's Debugger suggested to build cpython (or sth associated with it):

`path/to/my/python /opt/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace`

After I did this, Debugger now instantly returns this error:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

I found out that there was similar issue with cpython (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23273)
but I cannot use the workaround mentioned there because I am missing the files it suggest to remove...
I am not using cython, I wish I ignored this message about building it..

I am on linux (`SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried creating a new debug run configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did, no change.

Comment: This seems to happen regardless of python version. I get it when trying to debug code on a remote machine, in Pycharm Pro version; the interpreter I used was python3.5, from anaconda environment. Disabling PyQt (see re-gor's answer) solved the problem.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've fixed it by disabling `PyQt compatible` option in PyCharms's debugger settings (Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger). I don't use PyQt, so I have not met any troubles

Comment: @Mike No, I don't, sorry. I've never worked with PyQt.

Comment: I have PySide2 installed, but not PyQt. Disabling `PyQt compatible` worked for me as well as setting it to `PySide`. However, setting it to `PySide2` did not work even though that's what I have installed

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I tried this while debugging PyTorch, but it didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 42):

Goto pycharm -> Preferences -> Build,Execution and deployment -> Python debugger

Check box Collect run-time types information for code insight.

This solved issues for me.

Comment: this did not fix my problem debugging pytorch

Comment: Thank you!  That worked for me.  In contrast, the other answers I tried (checking Gevent and unchecking PyQt) did not solve it for me.

Comment: This solved the problem that occurred by only 10 lines of python code. I have tried to change the interpreter, which didn't work.

```
class Config:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.dict[item.upper()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Config()
```

Comment: By the way, does anybody know what is the feature of the `collect run-time types information for code insight`?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with 2018.3 after updating and installing Cython for fast debugging.

The issue was with `gevent` library.

Solved enabling `Gevent compatible` option and disabling PyQt compatible.

[image]

Comment: debugging pytorch, and this didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

I did change Pycharm from `2017.1.4` to `Pycharm EAP 2017.2`, but with no effect.

I solved the problem by making new python virtual environment and changing default Pycharm interpreter to it. Not the fastest solution I guess, but at least it worked.

Pycharm now again gives suggestions of building something for Cython, but now I just ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing all your breakpoints. Worked for me. Also check you have no problem when doing Run instead of Debug.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem in 2022.3 by clearing the many breakpoints I had

Comment: Amazingly this worked for me.

Comment: this worked for me in 2023

Comment: Worked for me too for PyTorch debugging. I didn't even had many breakpoints, maybe like 10. Cleared all and left only one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with James.

I meet the same question as you after I install PYQT. After I uninstall pyqt by Pycharm's "Preference->Project:your current project->Project Interpreter" find pyqt and push '-' button, the debug works.

What is interesting is that when I run a script which includes 'from PyQt4 import QtGui'. The pyqt package installed auto. And the debug does not work again. So I uninstall pyqt again and debug works one more time!

So I think there may be some package make debug not work , what you should do is just find and uninstall it. The crime package is often the pyqt, matplotlib or something similary.

Answer (score 2):

i meet this problem, and i search for it a long time, all caused by the compatible of pyqt,So I think a good idea to solve it....

- uninstall pyqt and matplotlib
- Fist install pyqt
- Second install matplotlib

then the problem was solved happily.

Comment: I also faced the same issue after PyCharm got updated to 2018.3.1 (professional). The code I am testing could be debug previously but not after update. Uninstalling and reinstalling pyqt, matplotlib worked.

Comment: The @re-gor solution worked once. I re-created my env and now I have no issues (at least few debugs)

Answer (score 1):

Mine worked after I removed pyqt5 bindings.

`sudo apt-get remove python3-pyqt5`

This wasn't happening to me because of building cpython. It was because I had installed an unrelated program. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly randomly enabled and disabled `Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging` and `PyQt compatible` until I found a version that was stable for me. Eventually it was stable at `Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging` enabled and `PyQt compatible` enabled at auto.

I also followed

```
 - uninstall pyqt and matplotlib
 - Fist install pyqt
 - Second install matplotlib
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same with 2017.1.4
Problem was resolved after update to 2017.1.5