# pytorch debugging timeout with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

I have a frustrating problem, where I cannot debug my pytorch code while in Pycharm.
While trying to inspect (breakpoint, then print e.g.) the code below, I receive a `"Loading time out"`

```py
import torch

    tensors = []
    num_tensors = 16
    shape = (1, 3, 512, 512)
    for i in range(num_tensors):
        tensors.append(torch.zeros(shape))
```

I saw this[[1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207752805-Debugging-SLOW-after-updating-to-2016-2),[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016449/pycharm-debugger-instantly-exits-with-139-code) posts, set variable loading policy to syncronyous, disabled Qt debugger options, and all the options specified, But I believe there is something basic I'm missing.

`pycharm 2019.2.5`, happens both in `python2` and `python3`.

Comment: Does it run fine?

Comment: I have the same problem. It does run fine, but the problem occurs when we want to debug.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `DataLoader`? If yes, you can try reducing the `num_workers` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Both with the Pycharm version 2019.3.3, 2019.3.4 and 2019.2.6. I had to revert back to 2018.3.7 where it was working. I may have some parameters that caused the conflicts.
It doesn't explain the underlying reason though...